# Vertical centre ::after on div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically centre an after pseudo-element with it's parent h1 element. I've used the `transform: translate(0,-50%);` to move it, but it isn't aligning properly. When inspecting the elements in developer tools, I get a h1 height of 37px and the after is correctly calculated at -18.5px.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
.container {
  max-width: 38rem;
  padding-left:  1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
  margin-left:  auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

h1::after {
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
  position:absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  content: "Heading one";

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <h1>Heading one</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `top: 50%;` to vertically center the text. Don't forget to use the left property with an absolute element so you won't have issues in any browser.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
.container {
  max-width: 38rem;
  padding-left:  1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
  margin-left:  auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

h1::after {
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
  position:absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  /* Top 50% */
  top: 50%;
  content: "Heading one";

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <h1>Heading one</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Booyah! That worked a treat. Thanks for the speedy response @Victor Allegret.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the `position: relative` on the `<h1>` element, and then setting the `position: absolute` on the `:after` pseudo-element.
Once that's done, you can set the `top:` attribute for that selector to `top: 50%`, then negate that with `transform: translateY(-50%)` (due to the way centering works).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
.container {
  max-width: 38rem;
  padding-left:  1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
  margin-left:  auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

h1::after {
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position:absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  content: "Heading one";

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <h1>Heading one</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Looking at the developer console, the pseudo-element sits perfectly centered on the `<h1>` tag.